# Ad Mediation setup and confusion

Tags: admob, ads, banner

I refer to [this Flurry page](http://Follow%20the%20same%20instructions%20used%20for%20integrating%20AdMob%20ads%20into%20your%20application.)

All I wan't to do is simply use Flurry as my main/primary ad network and then fall back to AdMob when there isn't a Flurry ad available. **Not the other way around**

With my current Ad Network (MobFox), all I needed to do was include the MobFox SDK (I have Google Play Games SDK Integrated already for Google Ads), and set up a custom event in my MobFox dashboard.  Simple as.  I request Ads via the MobFox SDK only.  Works beautifully.  If MobFox doesn't come up with an Ad, it goes to AdMob.  I can log into AdMob and see all of the stats etc.......

I've looked at another 4 networks and they all seem to say that I need 'Mediation Adaptors' (MobFox also has an adaptor, but they say it is only for when you want to Request Ads through AdMob and mediate out to MobFox -at least that's how I understood their explanation but they did say the mediation adaptor *wasn't required*).

These other networks also say I should 'request ads via AdMob' and log into AdMob to set up mediation on my account - something I've never had to do before.

I'm confused.  Are they talking about mediating from AdMob to some other network?  I wanna do it the other way around, should it be as simple a setup as I have with MobFox?

Ad Gurus please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You seem confused about what is doing the mediation and the role of the mediator.

Whatever component you setup as a mediator will hand off to one or more ad networks. That mediator will need to be given config for the ad networks that you intend on using. You will also need to provide the libraries for those ad networks in your app, and some adapter for each ad network for the mediator that you are using.

Admob provides a mediator as part of Google Play Services. It's mediator is configured via the Admob web site and most ad network libraries contain adapters for it.

Mobfox is an ad network, but may provide a mediation platform too (I don't know).

If you want mediation, with Flurry as primary and Admob as secondary then you need to choose a mediator and configure it with your accounts for each of those. I would use the mediator provided by Admob as then you will get your Admob network configured automatically and just need to configure the details for Flurry.

Comment: You're right @William, I am confused over this!  What you say makes sense.  I think the reason I'm getting confused is because I have never used or installed a 'mediation adaptor' when using MobFox so not sure why I have to install one for other networks when I have the AdMob (Google Play) SDK installed.  I'm also confused why MobFox has a mediation adaptor, but I don't need to use it to serve AdMob Ads through MobFox (With the MobFox SDK installed)!!  Thanks.

Comment: I believe MobFox mediates at the server end. SO all of your request go via MobFox and then it farms that out to other ad networks. Which means you don't need any mediation adapters or libraries for other networks. But it also means that MobFox is taking a cut of requests to other ad networks. Admob mediates at the client, which means you get to keep all the revenue from all of the requests. But it means you need libraries for each ad networks and mediation adapters for same.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should set it somehow manually in your AdMob account (or just try to ask the networks' support). For instance, I use Appodeal as a mediation platform. They support lots of networks (u just need to integrate their SDK), but at the same time you should link your AdMob account to Appodeal, using their plugin. After it, the platform shows most profitable ads automatically and it works perfect for me.
BTW what is your experience with MobFox?

Comment: Thanks @JohnBolino, MobFox initially said I needed to use their Mediation Adaptor, but when I explained what I was trying to do they said I didn't need it.  Maybe your answer explains why.  Are Mediation and Backfill 2 different things? In my case, (as far as I know) an Admob Ad will be shown only when a MobFox ad isn't available.  If they both have one available I don't think it picks the best one.   I have one app and it's hard to gauge MobFox's effectiveness because I never really did any promotion so didn't get many downloads - But why not give them a try? I might give appodeal a go.

Comment: Maybe I should give MoFox's mediation adaptor a go!!

Comment: To my mind backfill is not fully the same thing as mediation, these 2 notions are closely connected. Setup steps can be different with various mediating platforms, but the main idea is almost the same: u need to register  at the ad networks u choose as a developer, then u download their SDKs and complete the setting. There are many different ad networks, u need to set up them all and adjust their allocation percentages of traffic and backfill priorities at a mediation platform.

Comment: Then the mediation platform will monitor all ad networks and request ad from a higher priority network. If ad request comes back unfilled, the system will roll over to your backfill settings and continue down to a lower priority network and so on. The process of integration and setting up was quite simple with Appodeal, i described in the previous comment why, so give it a try! They have great, quickly responding support btw. Hope everything will be clarified, good luck.